# How to refactor Relational() to NetCore3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.0, entity-framework-core-3.0

I don't know how to choose the property after the revision.

```
private void ApplySnakeCaseNames(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
var mapper = new NpgsqlSnakeCaseNameTranslator();

        foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            // modify column names
            foreach (var property in entity.GetProperties())
            {
                property.Relational().ColumnName = mapper.TranslateMemberName(property.Relational().ColumnName);
            }

            // modify table name
            entity.Relational().TableName = mapper.TranslateMemberName(entity.Relational().TableName);

            // move asp_net tables into schema 'identity'
            if (entity.Relational().TableName.StartsWith("asp_net_"))
            {
                entity.Relational().TableName = entity.Relational().TableName.Replace("asp_net_", string.Empty);
                entity.Relational().Schema = "identity";
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect the output of keep the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `IMutableEntityType` and `IMutableProperty`, they expose the method instead of properties to change the Name.

Try something like below:

```
        foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            // modify column names
            foreach (var property in entity.GetProperties())
            {
                property.SetColumnName(mapper.TranslateMemberName(property.GetColumnName()));
            }

            // modify table name
            entity.SetTableName(mapper.TranslateMemberName(entity.GetTableName()));

            // move asp_net tables into schema 'identity'
            if (entity.GetTableName().StartsWith("asp_net_"))
            {
                entity.SetTableName(entity.GetTableName().Replace("asp_net_", string.Empty));
                entity.SetSchema("identity");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is breaking change in Entity Framework Core 3

```
IProperty.Relational().ColumnName -> IProperty.GetColumnName()
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#id=%22provider-specific-metadata-api-changes%22

Comment: my entity.GetProperties() in item => IMutableProperty
Sorry, I still don't understand how to modify it.